# How to replace "," with "." at the end line of a file?

Tags: c#, replace, filestream

I wrote below code to reformat a source text file(columns_original) and write to an output file(output.ctl). It is working but what I should do is, in the last line of output file created by below code, there is a "," at the end of the file and I want to change it to "."  In which part should I embed this code? I added this at the end but I am getting an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Output file is being used by another program"

```
// I am trying to replace "," with "." at the last line of the text I created      above and I created below code.

// I am trying to replace "," with ")" at the last line of the text I created above and 
using (FileStream aFile2 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(aFile2))
{
    var lastLine = File.ReadLines(path).Last();
    lastLine = lastLine.Replace(",", ".");
    sw2.WriteLine(lastLine);
}
```

MCVE:

```
 // I ADDED ABOVE CODE TO BELOW WORKING PART AND I AM GETTING ERROR MENTIONED IN THE POST  


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CTL_CMD_Creator
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ColChangable1 = "VARCHAR2";
        string ColChangable2 = "CHAR";
        string ColChangable3 = "NUMBER";
        string ColChangable4 = "DATE";

        string path = @"C:\Users\***\Desktop\output.ctl";

        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\***\Desktop\Columns_Original.txt");
        string line;

        using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {                       

                    string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '(', ')', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                    if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable1) || tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable2))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "\t" + "\"TRIM(:" + tokens[0] + ")\",");
                    }

                    else if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable3))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "\t" + ",");
                    }
                    else if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable4))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "\t" + "DATE" + ",");
                    }                        
                }
            }                
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post it on dotnetfiddle?

Comment: It's hard to understand where do you call replace function and where it fails.

Comment: You may rethink your main cycle. For example you can just do one simple Write operation to write line except ",", then on next iteration just do simple WriteLine(",") first, and after you exit from loop - just do additional WriteLine(".")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, a simpler way would be to use System.IO.File. [Demo on .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kNLvz6):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // init
        var path = "output.ctl";
        var content =
            "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine
            + "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine
            + ",";
        File.WriteAllText(path, content);

        var text = File.ReadAllLines(path); // read the file as string[]

        foreach (var line in text) // print the file
            Console.WriteLine(line);

        text[text.Length - 1] = text.Last().Replace(",", "."); // replace

        File.WriteAllLines(path, text); // overwrite or write to a new file

        string[] lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(path); // read again
        foreach (var line in lines2) // then print to show the difference
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

output:

```
Hello and Welcome
Hello and Welcome
,
Hello and Welcome
Hello and Welcome
.
```

Comment: You get whole file to the buffer. If file too big you will have out of the memory.

Comment: @MaxMokrousov True.

Comment: This answer did the trick. Thank you so much for your interest.

Answer (score 3):

Use [reader.EndOfStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.endofstream(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if it is End of file.

```
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '(', ')', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string line;

            if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable1) || tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable2))
            {
                line = tokens[0] + "\t" + "\"TRIM(:" + tokens[0] + ")";
            }

            else if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable3))
            {
                line = tokens[0] + "\t";
            }
            else if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable4))
            {
                line = tokens[0] + "\t" + "DATE";
            }

            line += reader.EndOfStream ? "." : ",";

            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

Comment: This appended to end so I got twice last line. Thank you for your kindness to answer my post.

Answer (score 2):

Would the following change to your code help at all?

I figured it would be easier to just test for a final write using (.hasNext())
Rather than closing and opening a new filestream.

which is your problem, you're trying to open a file with write access when it's still open.

```
using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {                       
                var delimiter = string.Empty; 

                string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '(', ')', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if(tokens.hasNext())
                { delimiter = ","; }
                else 
                { delimiter = "."; }

                if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable1) || tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable2))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "\t" + "\"TRIM(:" + tokens[0] + ")\" + delimiter);
                }

                else if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable3))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "\t" + delimiter);
                }
                else if (tokens[1].Equals(ColChangable4))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(tokens[0] + "\t" + "DATE" + delimiter);
                }                        
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time.

Answer (score 0):

For smaller files you could use:

```
public void Replace(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(outputFile, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(inputFile), @",\s*$", "."));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is neat.